# How to change content of image elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I change content of image elements similarly to changing content in p (HTML paragraph) elements? (refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)

I would like to have a scatter+sort effect button next to a default carousel view of images that when clicked, will, as you might have already guessed, scatter and sort itself in a stationery template.

Also, having the button change when clicked to flip between "Scatter+Sort" and "Carousel" views.

Here is what I have so far:
Carousel view - https://gyazo.com/18e67f7347de3310d155c0b8624b3716
Stationary view - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDmtS.jpg

What I intend on doing is following a similar approach to Jennifer Dewalt's a project a day for 180 days, except I am doing 100 projects in an indefinite time period.

**Update:** I got a button to bring up an image, but the container of images (carousel) is still on the page and does not vanish upon button click. Also, the image is shown as not available on the top left of screen before button click.

**Update 2:** Something I am looking into: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp . Animation iteration count of 1. I'm thinking maybe, if it's possible, to rewrite the container class (carousel) in css then pulling the code in an html file, so that way I can manipulate the elements within the container.

Comment: *How do I change content of image elements similarly to changing content in p (HTML paragraph) elements?* You don't because `img` elements don't / can't have content like a `p` element can. With an `img`, you'll need to modify its `src` attribute value at the appropriate time.

Comment: You mean, "You can't", hence why I said "similarly to". 

Is there a known method of modifying img src values via button click?  As well as having the button change upon click?

Comment: Yes you can definitely change the src value and the button on click with some jQuery.

Comment: The process is not similar to how it's done with a paragraph, which is why I answered the way I did. The process is straight-forward and I explained it above. Modify the `src` attribute when the button is clicked.

Comment: @DanielD JQuery is hardly needed for such an elementary operation. Can you use it? Sure. Do you need to? No.

Comment: @ScottMarcus if there's a tag for it, I'm going to suggest it.

Comment: @DanielD Fine. But, by not clarifying that it is not at all a real benefit for such an operation, you do the OP a dis-service.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Fair enough. I was honestly just trying to give a quick suggestion to help the OP get moving quicker. I figured at -5 this post may not be around for long..

Comment: @ScottMarcus You are mistaking the context in which I am using the phrase "similarly to". The concept remains the same: changing elements upon button click.

Comment: @DanielD Hey thanks Daniel! I'll try to find an open source jquery code on the internet, hopefully I don't come out empty-handed haha.

Comment: I do agree with @ScottMarcus 's sentiment that you are doing me a dis-service. Although I can understand why, as this post is receiving immediate negative attention.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I do not see your point of view when you called it an elementary operation, because I want an animation implementation of some sort that scatters the images from the carousel view into a stationary view. Sure, at its very core it is elementary, but I think not the same when implementing an animation effect.

Comment: You should try asking a specific question, not just asking people to design general functionality for you. can you show us your attempts? where you are encountering the error?

Comment: I am asking a specific question. Have you ever thought that maybe you aren't qualified or knowledgeable enough to answer the question at-hand?

Answer (score -2):

`document.getElementById("myImg").setAttribute("src", "my-new-image-source.jpg");`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: So, does this answer address "when" the source will change?